# web.config in folder allowing all or no user authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, web-config, location

I have a folder with several survey aspx pages. I have to set permissions on these aspx pages. There are 5 different pages and only one allows certain users to access. I have added a web.config file to allow and deny the users, but it's not working. If I allow my username and add a `deny="?"` I don't have access, but if I add another user, take mine out and take the deny option out I get permission to log onto the system. I can get access if I take deny out, but then all users is getting access to the page.

Adding my user credentials on and denying all anonymous users I don't get access. Can somebody please point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong?
Can it be that it is not reading or taking my windows logon credentials? I'm using visual studio 2012, entity framework.

This is what I've done:

```
   //Web Config that allows and denies:
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <configuration>
        <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
     </system.web>

    <location path="QualityCheckSurvey.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="DomainName\User2" />
        <deny users="?" /> 
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    </location>
    </configuration>
```

I have set my authentication mode to windows.

EDIT
It seems that the permissions were set incorrectly. But it's still not working. When I deny *, but allow USER1 the user don't get access even when prompted with a login request. The login windows dialog boks just keep on popping up 3times with even if the used have access. making it deny ? (anonymous) allows everybody to have access, even if I take out the deny and only have the allow tag with USER1 the rest of the users still have access... I'm running locally now, but even on the IIS when setting the authentication on there with (windows and basic authentication) does exactly the same....

EDIT
This is the actual code that I am using.  Only 3 users are allowed in this path "". This web.config file is within the survey folder with the 5 different types of surveys. Only this one survey should allow certain users, the rest of the surveys anyone can access....

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <location path="QualityCheckSurvey.aspx">
    <system.web>

      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="OEP\kevinh, OEP\shabierg, OEP\heilened" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
  </location>
```

In my main web.cofin in the root of the application I have set authentication mode to windows:

```
     <authentication mode="Windows">

<!--<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />-->
    </authentication>
```

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Is Windows Authentication enabled for the project?

Comment: @CodeCaster, Yes I have checked that it is enabled....

Comment: Is your request actually coming from "DomainName\User2"?  You may want to debug your project, and make sure Page.User is that ID (or Page.User.Identity.Name).

Comment: Yes, the domainname\User2 is working... I have edited the applicationhost.config file of IIS, it's giving me a popup to log in with my credentials, but it's still not allowing me to access it. the popup didn't appear until now....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On your question you said you have a folder name but on the web.config you have given only the file name on the path. Use the foldername/filename.aspx like below. Use deny users="*" instead of deny users="?'

```
<location path="foldername/QualityCheckSurvey.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="DomainName\User2"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**EDIT**

This looks like you have multiple web.config files in the same application. To avoid confusion just remove the one on the survey folder and on the root folder web.config add this code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <location path="survey/QualityCheckSurvey.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="OEP\kevinh, OEP\shabierg, OEP\heilened" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I am assuming the survey folder is inside the root folder.

Comment: Then it's not picking up the path of the aspx page. The error I get adding the folder name is: The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. 
Config Error

   Location path contains invalid characters 



Config File

   \\?\C:\Users\PCName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\NCTonerPublic\NCTonerPublic\Surveys\web.config

Comment: What is the path you gave? Just display the actual code here.. You should only give a relative path not full path. Are web.config and QualityCheckSurvey.aspx on the same folder?

Comment: it's still denying access to everyone... just keeps popping up the windows authentication screen... This is the error I get after 3 Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL. 

Error message 401.2.:Unauthorized:Logon failed due to server configuration.Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance

Comment: On the web server did you disable all authentication and enable windows authentication?

Comment: On the top you have said "the domainname\User2 is working." and here you have said, "it's still denying access to everyone". Which statement is true? If it is denying access to everyone then the issue might be the server is not joined to domain.

Comment: Domainname\User2 works when Deny="?" is added but not when it is made as Deny="*"... I don't want anonomous users to access, only certain users so Deny="*" has to be there to only allow certain users... If there is no deny at all everybody gets access, that is why I added the deny...

Comment: If you don't want anonymous disable anonymous access from IIS and Say allow users="*" and then display User.Identity.Name on a lable and check if your username is displayed.

Comment: I don't want to completely disable anonymous as they should have access to other web pages on the site, as well as the other surveys, this is the only survey/page that should only allow for certain users....

Comment: Did you try User.Identity.Name to see if your username is displayed?

Comment: User.Identity.Name returns a null value, so I'm using System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; to display the user identity (domainname\usernname)

Comment: Did you try my above solution? Remove the web.config from the survery folder and change the web.config on the root like I have suggested?

Comment: There was a module setting that was overwritten in the main.config which caused the problem...

Comment: I realize this is a bit of an old post... but I'm having the exact same issue. What did you mean "there was a module setting that was overwritten in the main.config"

Desperately trying to get to a solution here...

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing this error if windows authentication is added to project after it's been created

That's a mouthful. I was having this issue when I added Windows authentication to an existing project. There were a couple of key things that I needed to do before it works:

1. In Solution Explorer, Click on the project and then push F4. This should open up the Project properties.
2. In Project Properties and under the Development Server, make the following changes:

   - Anonymous Authentication: Disabled
   - Windows Authentication: Enabled
3. Include the following in the `Web.config` under `<system.web>`:

   ```xml
   <authorization>
     <allow users="DOMAIN\user"/>
     <deny users="*"/>
   </authorization>
   ```
4. Still in the `Web.config` under `<appSettings>`:

   ```xml
   <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
   ```

This is what worked for me. If I'm doing something wrong, please let me know.

Hopefully this will help future individuals who are working with windows authentication after creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
<deny users="?" /> 
<allow users="DomainName\User2" />
<deny users="*" />
```

Comment: It just keep popping up the windows authentication, but denies all users, nobody gets access....